# Make VStack fill images proportionally

Tags: swiftui, vstack, hstack, swiftui-scrollview

I'm doing the switch from UIKit to SwiftUI and I'm trying to achieve the following "Collection View".

[image]

Assuming I have an array of **pairs** (i.e: `[[<Image0>, <Image1>], <Image2>, <Image3>]]..`), my plan was to:

1. Create `ScrollView`
2. Create `HStack` and embed it inside the `ScrollView`
3. For each group, create `VStack` with some kind of filling proportional behavior

My current code:

```swift
struct AutoScrollingImages: View {
    let imageGroups: [[String]]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<imageGroups.count, id: \.self) { groupIndex in
                        VStack(spacing: .zero) {
                            ForEach(imageGroups[groupIndex], id: \.self) { imageName in
                                Image(imageName)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .cornerRadius(8.0)
                            }
                    }
                    .background(.gray)
                }
            }
        }.background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

But it fails horribly. I'd love help on this one.

Comment: Isn't imageName in ForEach an array?  If so, how could you get an image with Image([String, String])?

Comment: @ElTomato I'm loading the images via their name (String), they are in the asset catalog

Comment: Oops...  You have double `ForEach`.  My mistake...

Comment: I've tested it for myself.  It works.  So you have mistakes somewhere else you haven't discussed.

Comment: Are you sure? @ElTomato For me it's not maintaning the same width, so it's like both images aspect fit, but width is not aligned

Comment: No, I'm not.  It's not my job to guess what works on sample app in light of your statement which says 'it fails horribly.'

Comment: Also if you're trying to replicate a collection view, wouldn't a SwiftUI Grid be a better choice? That's the intended collection view replacement as I understand it.